# Linked Lists storing objects

Tags: singly-linked-list

this is my first question on Stack Overflow.  I have to implement a linked list Node class storing objects (this is homework for online class).  I have instantiated the objects and passed them as arguments to my Node class, but when I run my nodes come back as empty (null).  Any help on what I'm doing wrong?  I'm new to this!

```
public class Node {
Donor newDonor;
Node nextNode;
Node prevNode;
private Node head;


public Node() {

}

public Node(Donor newDonor) {

    nextNode = null;
    prevNode = null;
    this.head = null;

}


public Donor getDonor(){
    return newDonor;
}
public void setNewDonor(Donor newDonor) {
    this.newDonor = newDonor;
}
public void setDonor(Donor newDonor){
    this.newDonor = newDonor;
}
public Node getNextNode(){
    return nextNode;
}
public void setNextNode(Node nextNode){
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
}
public void setPrevNode(Node prevNode) {
    this.prevNode = prevNode;
}
public Node getPrevNode() {
    return prevNode;
}
public Node getHead() {
    return head;
}
public void setHead(Node head) {
    this.head = head;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Node{" + "newDonor=" + newDonor + ", nextNode=" + nextNode     + ",     prevNode=" + prevNode + '}';
}



public void addDonor(Donor newDonor) {

    Node newNode = new Node();
    if(head == null){
        newNode.setDonor(newDonor);
        newNode.setNextNode(head);
        head = newNode;
        System.out.println(toString());
    }
    else if(newDonor.getDonorID() < head.getDonor().getDonorID()){
        newNode.setNextNode(head);
        head = newNode;
    }
    Node current = head.getNextNode();
    Node previous = head;
    while (current != null && newNode.getDonor().getDonorID() >=current.getDonor().getDonorID()) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.getNextNode();
    }
    newNode.setNextNode(current);
    previous.setNextNode(newNode);
    //System.out.println(toString());
```

Comment: inside class Node() you are declaring newNode etc, then in addDonor you are creating a new local variable newNode, remove the "Node" infront of newNode in addDonor

Comment: Thanks, I tried it (after declaring newNode in my Node class since I forgot to do that) and removed the Node in front of newNode in my addDonor method, but still coming up with null on my System.out.println(toString()).  I only put this in to check if my head node was actually being populated with my object, but it still reads out null.